# What's the JUnit 5 way for RunListeners

Tags: junit5

In our environment we are using JUnit 4 `TestListener`s to report test results to a remote server.

What is the JUnit 5 way doing that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use a `TestExecutionListener`:

http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom

> 7.1.4. Plugging in Your Own Test Execution Listeners
>
> In addition to the public *Launcher API* method for registering test execution listeners programmatically, custom `TestExecutionListener` implementations discovered at runtime via Java’s `java.util.ServiceLoader` facility are automatically registered with the `DefaultLauncher`.

"JUnit 5", read the JUnit Platform, ships some example listeners. You can view their source here:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/tree/HEAD/junit-platform-launcher/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/launcher/listeners